# Can we preserve dependence in discretization?

Tags: causality, discrete-data, independence, discrete-distributions

Suppose we have two categorical random variables $X$ and $Y$, with both $k$ levels.

We assume $Y$ is generated causally from $X$ ($X \to Y$). We also assume causal Markovian is satisfied, which means $X$ and $Y$ are probabilistically dependent.

My question is:

- Is there always a way to re-discretize $Y$ into a new variable $\tilde{Y}$ with $l<k$ levels, such that $X$ is dependent with $\tilde{Y}$?

Comment: This is a great question, but I think we need some more assumptions on the levels. Without any restrictions on the levels, let me give you a counterexample: If $Y$ has exactly two levels, then there is no $\tilde{Y}$ with $l<k$ such that $X \sim \tilde{Y}$.

Comment: @Scriddie Hi thanks for your interest, I provide an answer below myself after some thinking. Please help check it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thinking, I believe the answer to my question is yes: there is always such a re-discretization as long as $k>l\geq2$.

The proof is as follows:

Denote the transition probability matrix from $X$ to $Y$ as $P(Y|X):=[pr(y_i|x_j)]_{i,j}$.

Then, $X \not \perp Y$ means at least two columns of $P(Y|X)$ are different (explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/608532/345167)). Without loss of generality, denote these two columns as $a:=[a_1,a_2,...,a_k]^T$ and $b:=[b_1,b_2,...,b_k]^T$, respectively, with $a \neq b$.

---

The re-discretization from $Y$ to $\tilde{Y}$ can be viewed as a transition with probabilities equal to $0$ or $1$. For example, re-discrete $Y \in \{y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4\}$ to $\tilde{Y} \in \{\tilde{y}_1, \tilde{y}_2\}$ with rules:

- $\tilde{Y}=\tilde{y}_1$ if $Y=y_1$ or $y_2$
- $\tilde{Y}=\tilde{y}_2$ otherwise

can be viewed as a probability transition from $Y$ to $\tilde{Y}$ with transition matrix $P(\tilde{Y}|Y)=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$. We will call such a transition matrix as the *re-discretization matrix* in the following.

A property of the re-discretization matrix is that there is only one $1$ in each column, with the other numbers in the column being $0$s.

---

The transition probability matrix from $X$ to $\tilde{Y}$ is  $P(\tilde{Y}|X)=P(\tilde{Y}|Y)P(Y|X)$. We have $\tilde{Y} \not\perp X$ if and only if there exist two different columns in $P(\tilde{Y}|X)$ (also explained [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/608532/345167)).

Denote the re-discretization matrix $P(\tilde{Y}|Y)$ as $M$ for simplicity. Consider the two columns $Ma$ and $Mb$ in $P(\tilde{Y}|X)$. We will show there is always a re-discretization matrix $M$ such that $Ma\neq Mb$, which shows $\tilde{Y} \not \perp X$.

Prove by contradiction. Suppose for any $M$, we have $Ma = Mb$. Then, let $M=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0
\end{bmatrix}$, we have $a_1=b_1$. Similarly, we have $a_i=b_i$ for $i=2,3,...,k$, which contradicts with the assumption that $a \neq b$.