# What kind of transition probability matrix indicates dependence/independence?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-process, discrete-data, discrete-distributions

Suppose we have two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$, both of which take values from $\{1,2,...,k\}$.

$Y$ is generated from $X$ via a transition probability matrix (also known as the [stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix)), which is defined as:

$$P:=[P_{ij}]_{k \times k}$$ with $P_{ij}=\mathrm{Pr}(X=j|Y=i)$.

My question is:

- Which kind of transition matrix $P$ results $X \perp Y$?
- $X \perp Y$ if and only if which property (such as trace, invertibility, *ect*.) the matrix $P$ has?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the sample space of both $X$ and $Y$ is finite, the independence boils down to finite number of constraints namely $P_{ij}$ as defined in the question should only depend on $j$ or in other words every row of $P$ should be the same (the distribution of $X$). It can be seen easily (for eg. using law of total probability) that this is also a sufficient condition for independence